# How can I protect specific areas of memory with Win32 API?

Tags: winapi, memory-management

Suppose I have a buffer of say 100 bytes as in `char *pBuffer = new char[100];` and I want to pass this to a third party function with specific instruction that it write into only the top half and that the bottom half is out of limits. How can I enforce that with Win32 API?

Thanks.

PS: This particular example might not be perfect but I am clear about my question.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does the 3rd party application have to access the read-only information in the array?

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to use [VirtualProtect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366898%28VS.85%29.aspx) to mark the last half as readonly. Since VirtualProtect works with pages, not bytes, you will in your example need to [VirtualAlloc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366887%28VS.85%29.aspx) `PAGE_SIZE` + 50 bytes, and adjust `pBuffer` so it matches your requirements.

Comment: @mousepad also take a look at this overview article about Windows virtual memory.  A bit old but still interesting.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810627.aspx